# Create Custom URL in Google Sheets with values from other cells

Tags: google-sheets, url-parameters

I am trying to create a custom URL inside Google sheets that uses a predetermined URL + values from particular cells. What im trying to create is a formula to create urls with parameters at scale for an email campaign.

example
domain.net

data I have

```
A1 Email
B1 Fname
C1 Lname
```

This is the desired result

```
domain.net??Email=A1&Fname=B1&Lname=C1

domain.net??Email=emailaddress&Fname=firstname&Lname=lastname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion I am completely missing the point but offer:

```
=D$1&"??"&A$1&"="&A1&"&"&B$1&"="&B1&"&"&C$1&"="&C1
```

in case that helps to indicate what additional clarification may be useful.

[image: SO48320263 example]